# Bootstrap tab navigation not working in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a vue.js application with 2 components that are routed. I tried to add a bootstrap tab navigation to the first component, but the tab contents are not displayed.

```
<template>
<div class="registration">
<ul  class="nav nav-pills">
 <li class="active">
  <a  href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
 </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a" >
    ---Content---
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="2a" >
    ---Content---
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'registration',
    data () {
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a structure as follows, run snippet to  understand more

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container">
  

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```